# mysql group_concat with a count inside?

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables, users and follows. table follows has a column named status. I would like to count how many follows each user has grouping by the status.

The query below returns a record for each status type for each user.

```
SELECT users.name as user_name, f.status, count(f.id) 
FROM users
JOIN application_follows f ON f.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id, f.status
ORDER BY users.id
```

returns something like:

```
user_name     status     count

mike          new         10
mike          old         5
tom           new         8
tom           old         9
```

but i would like something more friendly like:

```
user_name     status_count

mike          new,10|old,5
tom           new,8|old,9
```

tried using group_concat and count but didnt work. Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY twice, first on (user_id, status) from follows to get counts then on user_id from joined table to concat:

```
SELECT users.name, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(f.status, ',', f.cnt) SEPARATOR '|' )
FROM users 
JOIN
( SELECT user_id, status, count(id) AS cnt
  FROM application_follows
  GROUP BY user_id, status ) f
ON f.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know full tables definitions so I created query, which is using only user_name, status and count.

```
SELECT user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(status, ',', count) SEPARATOR '|')  FROM users GROUP BY user_name ORDER BY user_name;
```