# Count group_concat results

Tags: mysql

This question is very similar to [mysql group_concat with a count inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934361/mysql-group-concat-with-a-count-inside) but I couldn't figure how to apply to solution to my problem.

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    printer AS `Copieur/Imprimante`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groupname SEPARATOR "\r\n") AS `Groupes`,
FROM `assoc` 
WHERE groupname 
    IN (SELECT * FROM wanted_groups) 
GROUP BY printer;
```

Which gives me this :

[image: SQL results]

I would like to add the count of each printer-group, kind of like

```
\\simp\DSI - Canon iR C4580 PCL6    |   DSI-ECRITURE (20)
                                    |   DPDSI-ECRITURE (3)
...
```

Hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by pre-aggregating the data to get the count and then aggregating again to put the results into the format you want:

```
SELECT printer AS `Copieur/Imprimante`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(groupname, ' (', cnt, ')' SEPARATOR '\r\n') AS `Groupes`
FROM (SELECT printer, groupname, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM `assoc`
     WHERE groupname IN (SELECT * FROM wanted_groups) 
      GROUP BY printer, groupname
     ) a 
GROUP BY printer;
```

Comment: I had to remove 1 comma and correct group_name -> groupname but this WORKS. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JeanneD4RK . . . Glad you figured it out.  Cheers.