# Mysql group concat with counting items

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, 'item' and 'propvalues', propvalues have property_id and value column, what im trying to get is to group propvalues as property_id, and count how many similar values they have.

i know it is similar to another question, but i was unable to figure out how to change it for myself to work. if someone is good at mysql please dont mark it as a duplicate question, but rather try to give me at least some advice. i dont understand what is going on when there is an inner select statement

Here are the tables:

```
'item'
  id    category_id
   1         1
   2         1
   3         2
   4         5
   etc.

'propvalues'
  id    item_id    property_id       value
  1       1           3               'blue'
  2       1           3               'blue'
  3       1           3               'blue'
  4       1           3               'red'
  5       1           5               'blue'
  6       1           5               'red'
  7       2           5               'red'

SELECT propvalues.property_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(propvalues.value) 
FROM propvalues JOIN item ON item.id = propvalues.item_id
WHERE item.category_id = 1 || item.category_id = 2
GROUP BY propvalues.property_id
```

**this give this result:**

```
property_id      value
    3          blue,blue,blue,red
    5          blue,red,red
```

but **i need this**, result, i want only the unique values,and count them:

```
3        blue,3|red,1
5        blue,1|red,2
```

any ideas ?
i found some solution here: [mysql group_concat with a count inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934361/mysql-group-concat-with-a-count-inside)
but im unable to figure out how to change it for myself to work.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate, because the problem is basically the exact same as in the other question you linked to. And if you really tried to implement/adapt that for your situation, then at least show us what you tried and with what results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql group\_concat with a count inside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934361/mysql-group-concat-with-a-count-inside)

Comment: i dont understand how that works, if i would im not asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived from the [refered duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934501/2677334):

```
SELECT property_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(value, ',', cnt) SEPARATOR '|')
FROM (
    SELECT property_id, value, COUNT(value) AS cnt
    FROM propvalues
    JOIN item ON item.id = propvalues.item_id
        AND item.category_id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY property_id, value
) t
GROUP BY property_id
```

To break it down, the inner subquery fetches a number of distinct values per property_id:

```
+-------------+-------+-----+
| property_id | value | cnt |
+-------------+-------+-----+
|           3 | blue  |   3 |
|           3 | red   |   1 |
|           5 | blue  |   1 |
|           5 | red   |   2 |
+-------------+-------+-----+
```

The outer main query further aggregates theses values by distinct property_id, concatenates value and count to a string (`CONCAT(value, ',', cnt)`) and then concatenates those from each row (`GROUP_CONCAT(... SEPARATOR '|')`).

Comment: error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'base.propvalues.item_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You're right, that didn't work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you some much Joe !! It works perfectly. I will try to learn from it