# Generating a counting number inside a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, group-concat

How can I get a counting number inside of a GROUP_CONCAT. The idea is that for each element it would increase but would then reset back to 0 for the next row.

I have seen similar questions like this one:
[mysql group_concat with a count inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934361/mysql-group-concat-with-a-count-inside)
But I am still confused with how to handle it with my specific query.

I am using laravel 4.2

Here is my code and table structures:

```
$Project::leftJoin('tasks as t', 'projects.id', '=', 't.project_id')
          ->leftJoin('equipments as e', 't.equipment_id', '=', 'e.id')
          ->leftJoin('processes as p', 'e.process_id', '=', 'p.id')
          ->select(array(
                'projects.id',
                DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('Task # - ', p.name,' / ', e.`name`, '') separator ' | ') as tasks"),
            ))
            ->groupBy('projects.id');
```

My Table structure and data are as follows:

*projects*

```
+----------------+
|  id            |
+----------------+
|  1             |
|  2             |
|----------------+
```

*tasks*

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  id            |  project_id    |  equipment_id  |
|  1             |  1             |  1             |
|  2             |  1             |  3             |
|  3             |  2             |  2             |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

*equipments*

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  id            |  process_id    |  name          |
|  1             |  1             |  Xerox X       |
|  2             |  1             |  Samsung C     |
|  3             |  2             |  TL4000        |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

*processes*

```
+----------------+----------------+
|  id            |  name          |
|  1             |  Printing      |
|  2             |  Binding       |
+----------------+----------------+
```

The desire output would be a list of projects that show the task and equipment used by each:

```
projects.id     |     tasks
```

```
      1         |    Task 1 - Printing / Xerox X | Task 2 - Binding - TL4000
                |    
      2         |    Task 1 - Printing / Samsung C
```

The task number would increment but for the next project group it would reset back to 1.

Comment: This is surely a task for your application code? Just use a regular query to grab a well-ordered array, and then handle everything else in your application.

Comment: Normally I would do that, unfortunately though in this case I need to do it in the query if it is possible and doesn't affect performance too much.