# count not working inside group_concat Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concat count of id and 1 inside group_concat. Below is my query.

MYSQL:

```
SELECT
months.name AS NAME,
CONCAT(
    '[',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            '[\"',
            COUNT(p_c_n_details.JPN_ID),
            '\",',
            1,
            ']'
        )
    ),
    ']'
) AS DATA
FROM
p_c_n_details
INNER JOIN in_e_s_s__p_c_ns RIGHT OUTER JOIN months ON months.id = 
MONTH(p_c_n_details.created_at) AND p_c_n_details.type IN('Process Change', 
'Design Change') AND p_c_n_details.JPN_ID = 
in_e_s_s__p_c_ns.juniperinternalpcnid AND p_c_n_details.created_at >= 
last_day(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
WHERE
months.name IN(
    MONTHNAME(
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH)),
        MONTHNAME(
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),
            MONTHNAME(
                DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
            )
        GROUP BY
            months.id
```

Expected Output:

```
Name   |     DATA
-------------------------
July        [20,1]
August       [33,1]

Table months contains month names.
```

But I am getting error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function.` I tried this link 
[mysql group_concat with a count inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934361/mysql-group-concat-with-a-count-inside)
 but I am facing error when using in my query.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `COUNT()` are both aggregate functions. You can't nest one inside the other. If you showed us some sample input and desired output we might be able to help you figure out how to structure your query.

Comment: @O.Jones Hi Jones I updated my question and added sample output. Please check.

Comment: I don't understand where how you get the `2` in  `{33,2}`. I also don't understand how the `{}` characters come from the `[]` characters in your sample query.

Comment: @O.Jones I changed it is not 2 it is 1 default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess.

Try:

```
SELECT months.name AS NAME,
      CONCAT('{',COUNT(p_c_n_details.JPN_ID),',1}' AS DATA
```

in place of the SELECT you now have.

Your example result doesn't show a need for `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Thanks Jones.You are right GROUP_CONCAT() is not needed.